# Cpp swapping dimensions within multidimensional vector

Tags: c++

Hey I´m sorry if this question was already asked or other answers could be combined to approach what I´m looking for. But I´m fairly new to Cpp and the STL stuff can be quite overwhelming, so don´t be too judgy please and link me to the corresponding answers please. I´m glad if someone can help me:

I have a multidimensional vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<definedTyp>>>> startingVec;
```

and I want to "swap" the first 2 dimensions like: Let´s say `startingVec` has the dimensions `[dim, batches, batchSize, length]` and I want to `swap` the first 2 dimensions leading to `[batches, dim, batchSize, length]`. So far I defined a new vector and build a workaround with ugly for loops and just appended the corresponding vectors but I´m looking for an elegant way and I´m willing to learn the STL (algorithms) :)
Hopefully my problem became clear. Thanks in advance.

`Edit`: I don´ t know if it´s important but the dimensions within `batchSize` differ as the last batch is likely to be smaller than the preceding batches.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue

Comment: This sounds like you rather want a single (flat) vector and use a custom indexing function to facilitate multiple dimensions. That would make swapping elements around simpler and you have better memory locality.

Comment: Also, instead of swapping the elements around, you could also adapt the indexing function to calculate the flat index differently so it looks like you swapped dimensions without actually having to touch the memory at all. Depending on your usage this could drastically improve or drastically negate your performance

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Hope my code helps. @Timo: Could you please be more precise on this? So you mean unrolling ```[dim, samples, length]``` to a single vector of length ```[dim*samples*length]``` and write an indexing function that builds my final ```[batches, dim, batchSize, length]``` output ? I think memory is not the problem. The vectors are of managable size. Nevertheless I´m thankful if I get help for an efficient method :)

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<` yea scrap that code

Comment: Haha you are right. I come from a scientific background and if it works it´ s fine. But i want to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment, you could use 1 flat vector to store all your data, and specific sorting functions to access it in the order you want. Here's an example with unrelated (but clearer) data structure to illustrate:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    size_t age;
    size_t height;
    float weight;
    
    static bool isYounger(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return p1.age < p2.age; }
    static bool isShorter(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return p1.height < p2.height; }
    static bool isLighter(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return p1.weight < p2.weight; }
};

template<typename Func_>
std::vector<size_t> generatesortedIdxBy(const std::vector<Person>& persons, Func_ sortingFunc) {
    std::vector<size_t> res ( persons.size() );
    std::iota(res.begin(), res.end(), 0);
    std::sort(res.begin(), res.end(), 
        [&](size_t id1, size_t id2){return sortingFunc(persons.at(id1), persons.at(id2));});
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    // Your "flat" data vector
    std::vector<Person> persons { 
        { "Alice", 60, 160, 45.f },
        { "Bob", 57, 180, 75.f }, 
        { "Charles", 30, 175, 108.f }, 
        { "David", 24, 165, 80.f }
    };
        
    // Your index vectors to access your data in different order
    std::vector<size_t> idxByAge = generatesortedIdxBy(persons, Person::isYounger); // { 3, 2, 0, 1 }
    std::vector<size_t> idxByHeight  = generatesortedIdxBy(persons, Person::isShorter); //{ 0, 3, 2, 1 }
    std::vector<size_t> idxByWeight = generatesortedIdxBy(persons, Person::isLighter); // { 0, 1, 3, 2 }
    
    
    std::cout << "By age: " << std::endl;
    for (auto idx: idxByAge) { 
        Person& person = persons.at(idx);
        std::cout << person.name << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "By height: " << std::endl;
    for (auto idx: idxByHeight) { 
        Person& person = persons.at(idx);
        std::cout << person.name << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "By weight: " << std::endl;
    for (auto idx: idxByWeight) { 
        Person& person = persons.at(idx);
        std::cout << person.name << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. I´ll see how I can adapt this to my data structure. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a templated version of a multidimensional array. It requires C++20 to compile. This is not production ready code and could be done cleaner if you put a little more effort into the matter.

As I said in the comments, this array stores all its elements in a flat 1D array. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/j6a1nh) is an example with some comments.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Dims>
class Tensor 
{
public:
    Tensor(Dims... dims) : 
        dimensions{dims...},        
        data((dims * ...))
    {        
        std::exclusive_scan(dimensions.crbegin(), dimensions.crend(), dimensionSizes.rbegin(), 1, std::multiplies<>{});
    }

    T& operator()(Dims... indices)
    {
        auto flatIndex = calcIndex(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Dims)>{}, std::forward_as_tuple(indices...));
        return data[flatIndex];
    }

    template <std::size_t ...I>
    std::size_t calcIndex(std::index_sequence<I...>, std::tuple<Dims...> indices)
    {        
        return ((get<I>(indices) * dimensionSizes[I]) + ...);
    }

    std::vector<T>& getData() 
    {
        return data;
    }

    const auto& getDimensions() const 
    {
        return dimensions;
    }

private:        
    std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)> dimensions{};
    std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dims)> dimensionSizes{};
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```